# Spring / Hibernate. Converting a String to Date with the same timezone in web service and insert to SQL

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, hibernate, datetime

I have a string in json that a webservice receives. The webservice is supposed to hit the SQL database with the time on the string. The code

```
String str = "Fri Feb 05 11:00:50 GMT+07:00 2016";

DateFormat dF = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy");

java.util.Date date = dF.format(str);
```

and now date.toString() becomes date in UTC timezone

```
"Fri Feb 05 04:00:50 UTC 2016"
```

and when saved in the Database using Spring/Hibernate, it uses that time in UTC even though SQL does not store the time zone since it is DateTime.

My current hack is getting the offset add it to the new Date object so that it becomes

```
"Fri Feb 05 11:00:50 UTC 2016"
```

and even though it is now the wrong time, it does not matter when saved in SQL because it doesn't store the timezone.

Other than my hack, is there any other Date utility (like sql.datetime, or joda) which can fix my problem? Thanks before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joda-Time supports this with an annotation and mapping. I guess it is what you are looking for: [Hibernate mapping](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/contrib/hibernate/userguide.html)